# how to solve android service has leaked error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory-leaks, android-service

I have an activity that calls a service on its onCreate , however when I try yo run the project  I keep getting an error saying the service has leaked and longer bound on the activity that called/registered  it .

"Activity com.xera.deviceinsight.home.DataUsageActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.xera.deviceinsight.home.DataUsageActivity$3@42676a48 that was originally bound here" I am assuming this might have something to do with the lifecycle of the activity . I have both the activity and the service in question below

**myActivity**

```
 public class DataUsageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MonitorService.ServiceCallback
    {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          TinyDB settings = new TinyDB(this);
          if (settings.getBoolean(AppPreferences.HAS_LOGGED_IN))
          {


             this.bindService(
                     new Intent(this, MonitorService.class),
                     serviceConnection,
                     Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
             return;
          }

          }


     public void sendResults(int resultCode, Bundle b)
       {
         // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }

         private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
       {
          @Override
          public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
          {
             MonitorService.LocalBinder binder = (MonitorService.LocalBinder)service;
             backgroundService = binder.getService();
             backgroundService.setCallback(DataUsageActivity.this);
             backgroundService.start();
          }

          @Override
          public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className)
          {
             backgroundService = null;
          }
       };


        @Override
       public void onResume()
       {
          super.onResume();
          if(backgroundService != null)
          {
             backgroundService.setCallback(this);
          }
       }


       @Override
       public void onPause()
       {
          super.onPause();
          if(backgroundService != null)
          {
             backgroundService.setCallback(null);
          }
       }


      }



   **myService**
```

public class MonitorService extends Service
       {

```
    private boolean initialized = false;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private ServiceCallback callback = null;
    private Timer timer = null;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private String foreground = null;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> processList;
    private ArrayList<String> packages;
    private Date split = null;
    // private Date startTime = null;
    public int timeCheckVariable = 0 ;

    public static int SERVICE_PERIOD = 5000; // TODO: customize (this is for scan every 5 seconds)

    private final ProcessList pl = new ProcessList(this)
    {
        @Override
        protected boolean isFilteredByName(String pack)
        {
            // TODO: filter processes by names, return true to skip the process
            // always return false (by default) to monitor all processes
            return false;
        }
    };

    public interface ServiceCallback
    {
        void sendResults(int resultCode, Bundle b);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder
    {
        MonitorService getService()
        {
            // Return this instance of the service so clients can call public methods
            return MonitorService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        initialized = true;
        processList = ((DeviceInsightApp)getApplication()).getProcessList();
        packages = ((DeviceInsightApp)getApplication()).getPackages();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        if(initialized)
        {
            return mBinder;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setCallback(ServiceCallback callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    // private boolean addToStatistics(String target , Long startTime)
    private boolean addToStatistics(String target )
    {
        boolean changed = false;
        Date now = new Date();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(target))
        {
            if(!target.equals(foreground))
            {
                int i;
                // timeCheckVariable = i ;
                if(foreground != null && split != null)
                {
                    // TODO: calculate time difference from current moment
                    // to the moment when previous foreground process was activated
                    i = packages.indexOf(foreground);
                    timeCheckVariable = i ;
                    long delta = (now.getTime() - split.getTime()) / 1000;
                    Long time = (Long)processList.get(i).get(ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME);
                    if(time != null)
                    {
                        // TODO: add the delta to statistics of 'foreground'
                        time += delta;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        time = new Long(delta);
                    }

                    processList.get(i).put(ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME, time);
                    //String applicationName = (String)processList.get(i).get(ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_NAME);
                   // DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
                  //  int x = time.intValue( );
                   // db.addAppRecord(new AppUsageClass(applicationName  , x));
                   // db.getApplicationCount();
                   // List<AppUsageClass> appUsageClass = db.getAllApplications();
                   // db.getApplicationCount();
                   // for (AppUsageClass cn : appUsageClass) {
                        //String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,ApplicationName : " + cn.getName() + " ,TimeSpent: " + cn.getTimeSpent();

                       // Log.d("Name: ", log);
                    //}
                }

                //update count of process activation for new 'target'
                i = packages.indexOf(target);
                Integer count = (Integer)processList.get(i).get(ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_COUNT);
                if(count != null) count++;
                else
                {
                    count = new Integer(1);
                }
                processList.get(i).put(ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_COUNT, count);
                foreground = target;
                split = now;
                changed = true;
            }
        }
        //Long checkTimeNow = (Long)processList.get(timeCheckVariable).get(ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME);
        return changed;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if(timer == null)
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new MonitoringTimerTask(), 500, SERVICE_PERIOD);
        }

        // TODO: startForeground(srvcid, createNotification(null));
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }

    private class MonitoringTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            fillProcessList();
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)MonitorService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
            String current = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName(); // gets the application which is in the foreground
            int  i = packages.indexOf(current);
            Long timecheck = (Long)processList.get(i).get(ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME);
            if(addToStatistics(current)&& callback != null)
            {
                final Bundle b = new Bundle();
                // TODO: pass necessary info to UI via bundle
                mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        callback.sendResults(1, b);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    private void fillProcessList()
    {
        pl.fillProcessList(processList, packages);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't unbind from you service in .onPause() or in .onDestroy(), so if you Activity is destroyed, connection still last, so there is leaked connection. If you want you service to run all the time, you should start it by .startService() and then bind to it. In .onStop() or .onDestroy() unbind from that service

Comment: thank you for that . I would like to keep my service running all the time .

Comment: `this.bindService(
                 new Intent(this, MonitorService.class),
                 serviceConnection,
                 Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`  how do I make use of startService seeing as I am already using bindService ?